# Save the active open document as pdf file

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, ms-word

I have the below code that copy range cell values from excel and paste as picture in a new word document.
I want to save the active document as pdf file with name of file as value in cell "A2".
If you can help me in adding the same in the below code it would be a great help.

```
Sub Picture()
Dim objWord, objDoc As Object
ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
Range("A2:K25").Select
Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
objWord.Visible = True
objWord.Selection.Paste
objWord.Selection.TypeParagraph

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
Sub SaveAsPDF()
    Dim objWord, objDoc As Object
    Dim A2 As String
    Dim Crng As Range

    A2 = Range("A2")
    Set Crng = Range("A2:K25")

    Crng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
    objWord.Visible = True
    objWord.Selection.Paste
    objWord.Selection.TypeParagraph

    With objDoc
        .ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
                             "C:\Users\Dave\Downloads\" & A2 & ".pdf", ExportFormat:=17, _
                             OpenAfterExport:=True, OptimizeFor:=0, Range:= _
                             0, From:=1, To:=1, Item:=0, _
                             IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, CreateBookmarks:= _
                             0, DocStructureTags:=True, BitmapMissingFonts:= _
                             True, UseISO19005_1:=False
        .Close saveChanges:=False
    End With
    objWord.Quit
    Set objWord = Nothing

End Sub
```

Instead of using word to PDF use excel

```
Sub SaveAsPDFxlStyle()
    Dim objWord, objDoc As Object
    Dim A2 As String

    A2 = Range("A2")
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$2:$K$25"

    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintGridlines = True
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
    End With

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
                                    "C:\Users\Dave\Downloads\" & A2 & ".pdf", Quality:= _
                                    xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                                    OpenAfterPublish:=0

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you.. Its worked great. Only issue I am facing now is the word doc and pdf files are still open. It should get closed as well.

Comment: Change `OpenAfterExport:=True` to false, then the pdf won't open up. The line `.Close saveChanges:=False` should close the word doc.

Comment: Could you not have `Crng.CopyPicture` to a different worksheet and the PDF'd that worksheet?

Comment: .Close saveChanges:=False only close the active document not the entire word doc.